# Pandas: vectorize sliding time window aggregation

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a big dataframe from which I need sliding time windows averages for a given set of query points. I tried with `df.rolling` but this wouldn't allow me for querying arbitary points. The following works, but seems inefficient and does not allow for vectorized usage:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': range(5)},
              index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
query = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='s')
time_window = pd.Timedelta(seconds=2)

f = lambda t: df[(t - time_window < df.index) & (df.index <= t)]["B"].mean()

[f(t) for t in query] # works but is slow
f(query) # throws ValueError length must match
```

Probably this can be done better ...

Edit: The real application has measures which appear randomly between 30 and 90 seconds. Sometimes there are periods with several days or weeks without data. The `time_window` is typically 15 minutes. The overall time horizon is 10 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I came up with the following solution with two rolling windows, one for entering the window and one for leaving:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': range(5)},
              index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
query = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='s')
time_window = pd.Timedelta(seconds=2)

aggregates = ['mean']
### Preparation
# one data point for each point entering the window
df1 = df.rolling(window=time_window, closed='right').agg(aggregates)

# one data point for each point leaving the window - use reverted df
df2 = df[::-1].rolling(window=time_window, closed='left').agg(aggregates)
df2.index += time_window
# Caution: for my real data in the reverted rolling method, I had
# to add a small Timedelta to window to function properly

# merge both together and remove duplicates
df_windowed = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_windowed.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_windowed = df_windowed[~df_windowed.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

### the vectorized function
# Caution: get_indexer returns -1 for not found values (below df.index.min()), 
# which is interpreted as last value. But last value of df_windows is always NaN
f = lambda t: df_windowed.iloc[
        df_windowed.index.get_indexer(t, method='ffill') if isinstance(t, (pd.Index, pd.Series, np.ndarray,)) else
        df_windowed.index.get_loc(t, method='ffill')
    ]["B"]["mean"].to_numpy()

f(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're skipping just a small step.

Your "query" is really a time series resampling operation. That is, in addition to calculating a rolling mean, you are also trying to smoothly resample the time series at a frequency of one second. You can do that using the [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) method, applying it prior to the rolling operation:

```
resample_rolling = df.asfreq('1s').rolling(pd.Timedelta(seconds=2)).mean()
 
print(np.array([f(t) for t in query]))
print(resample_rolling.to_numpy()[:, 0])
```

Output:

```
[0.  0.  1.  1.5 2.  3.  3.5]
[0.  0.  1.  1.5 2.  3.  3.5]
```

Note that by default, the `asfreq` method fills missing values in with `nan` values.

```
>>> df.asfreq(pd.Timedelta(seconds=1))
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:05  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0
```

The rolling operation then ignores those values. If instead you want to fill the values with something other than `nan`s, you have two options. You can supply a `fill_value`:

```
>>> df.asfreq('1s', fill_value=0.0)
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0
```

Or you can specify a `method`, such as `backfill`, which uses the next value in the series:

```
>>> df.asfreq('1s', method='backfill')
                     B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  1
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2
2013-01-01 09:00:04  3
2013-01-01 09:00:05  3
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4
```

The resulting rolling mean is then different, of course:

```
>>> df.asfreq('1s', method='backfill').rolling('1s').mean()
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0
```

Comment: Ok. I do understand the approach, which works fine if the time between measures is small. In my real case the time between measures varies more or less randomly between 30 and 90 s, time_windows is 15 min and I have 10 years of data. So asfreq('1s') would create many NaN.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a different parameter than `'1s'`? `asfreq` accepts arbitrary `Timedelta`s, among other things.

Comment: I thought about this, but the resolution of the measurements is in seconds. I would need to round the index to minutes, which might introduce inaccuracies if two measures just differ by 30 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't understood something about your question. Your slow solution resamples the data at a frequency of one second. But it sounds like that's not actually what you want to do after all. What exactly do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Thanks for your patience and I'm sorry for being unprecise. Measurements haven been taken roughly every minute (30 to 90 seconds) in the last 10 years. For an equidistant set of query points (typically for a range of 1 hour 50 points), I'd like to have the 15 minute average.

Comment: OK, I follow at least partially. And is your concern about `nan` values a memory issue? Because if not, the `nan` values can easily be filtered out after the fact. And even if it is a memory issue, a batch-wise approach would probably work. I'll try to create a synthetic test DataFrame to show how.